# create tar and save it to stdout

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to create tar from a file, which contains list of other files and saving it to stdout.

let suppose there is a file called "**files-to-create**" which has path of other files like **/home/abc.txt /home/def.txt** and I want to create tar of **abc.txt,def.txt**.

my script contains:

```
exec 100>&1
tar cf - -T files-to-sync >&100
```

and I am calling the script and saving it to some other file like:

`/script.sh > final_tar.tar`

But while creating the tar I am getting error, can somebody help me out?

Comment: what is the exact error you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to reach your goal, let me know if something is unclear:

**Prototype 1:**

```
$ cat scriptTar.sh 
#!/bin/bash

readonly HELP="$(basename "$0") <list_of_files> <output_tar>

this script will generate a tar file composed of all files present in <list_of_files> input file
the output tar file will be saved as <output_tar>
to run the script provide the input and output filenames"

readonly INPUT_LIST_FILE=$1
readonly OUTPUT_TAR_FILE=$2
if [ -z "$INPUT_LIST_FILE" -o -z "$OUTPUT_TAR_FILE" ]
then
 echo $HELP; 
 exit 1;
fi

tar cf - -T $INPUT_LIST_FILE > $OUTPUT_TAR_FILE 
exit $?
```

**Folder content:**

```
$ tree .
.
├── a
│   └── abc.txt
├── b
│   └── def.txt
├── c
│   └── ghj.txt
├── files-to-sync.in
└── scriptTar.sh

3 directories, 5 files
```

**List file content:**

```
$ cat files-to-sync.in 
./a/abc.txt
./b/def.txt
./c/ghj.txt
```

**Execution:**

```
$ ./scriptTar.sh files-to-sync.in output.tar
```

**tar file content:**

```
$ tar -tvf output.tar                                                                                                                          
-rw-rw-r-- arobert/arobert   4 2018-02-22 16:50 ./a/abc.txt
-rw-rw-r-- arobert/arobert   4 2018-02-22 16:50 ./b/def.txt
-rw-rw-r-- arobert/arobert   4 2018-02-22 16:50 ./c/ghj.txt
```

Or use the following script if you really want to display it on stdout:

**Prototype 2 via ssh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly HELP="ERROR: $(basename "$0") <list_of_files> 

this script will generate to stdout a tar file composed of all files present in <list_of_files> input file
to run the script provide the input file and redirect the output to a file"

readonly INPUT_LIST_FILE=$1
if [ -z "$INPUT_LIST_FILE" ]
then
 echo $HELP; 
 exit 1;
fi

tar cf - -T $INPUT_LIST_FILE
```

**Execution via ssh:**
    $ ssh user@localhost "cd /home/user/test_tar/; ./scriptTar.sh files-to-sync.in" > output.tar
    user@localhost's password:

**Content of the tar generated:**

```
tar -tf output.tar
./a/abc.txt
./b/def.txt
./c/ghj.txt
```

**extracting the content:**

```
tar xvf output.tar 
./a/abc.txt
./b/def.txt
./c/ghj.txt
```

**checking the files:**

```
more ?/*.txt
::::::::::::::
a/abc.txt
::::::::::::::
abc
::::::::::::::
b/def.txt
::::::::::::::
abc
::::::::::::::
c/ghj.txt
::::::
```

**However if I were you, I would not only generate a tar file but add some compression (`tar.gz`) and transfer the file with `rsync` to be able to restart the download from the point where it stopped in case of transfer error.**

Comment: Actually I am calling the script from other server. So the case is server1 has the script and from server 2 I am calling the script of server1 using ssh. from server2 I am doing `ssh server1 "/run_the_script.sh" > final_tar.tar`

Comment: why don't you use `scp` to transfer the tar file from one server to another? After the tar file is created?

Comment: Its a humongous tarball so scp will make things slow. Can't we do it like I was trying in the problem statement

Comment: while using this command in terminal I am getting this: `tar cf - -T files-to-sync` Error: `tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
`

Comment: I have edited my post to take into account the ssh connection, try it! It works  fine for me ;-)

Comment: your solution is working fine only if I am passing the `$INPUT_LIST_FILE` as an argument. But if you specify the path of the file rather than taking it as an argument it is throwing an error.

Comment: Got it, if you want to pass an absolute path you have to use `-P` for security reason. Because according to man page if you use` -T` "<b>They undergo quote removal and word splitting</b>" so right command is: `tar cfP - -T absolute_path_of_the_file`

Answer (score 1):

So the proper solution is

Case1: **If you are passing the list of file as an argument**

you can use this:

```
files-to-sync=$1
tar cf - -T files-to-sync
```

Case2: **If you want to use absolute path for the list of file**

you can use this:

```
tar cfP - -T /path/to/the/file
```

**use -P in case of absolute path.**